# stringFromCharCode equivalent for Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I have a string which I want to insert to an ObjC `NSURL.UrlWithString` function, but it has to be without any quotes.

bad example:

```
$.NSURL.URLWithString("http://192.168.1.1")
```

In JavaScript, I know I can do something like `StringFromCharCode(34,90,81,33)` to avoid quotes, but what is the alternative in Objective C? (not Swift).

Answer (score 2):

### JS String.fromCharCode()

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode):

> The static `String.fromCharCode()` method returns a string created from the specified sequence of UTF-16 code units.

```js
console.log(String.fromCharCode(189, 43, 190, 61));
// expected output: "½+¾="
```

### Obj-C NSString

```c
+ (instancetype)stringWithCharacters:(const unichar *)characters 
                              length:(NSUInteger)length;
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1497248-stringwithcharacters?language=objc):

> Returns a string containing a given number of characters taken from a given C array of UTF-16 code units.

#### Example

```c
unichar chars[] = {189, 43, 190, 61};
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithCharacters:chars
                                      length:sizeof(chars) / sizeof(unichar)];
NSLog(@"%@", s);
// expected output: ½+¾=
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know C's printf syntax? Then use something similar with characters

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%c%c%c", 34, 90, 81, 33];
```

or repeatedly append to a (mutable) string one string at a time you create like this with a character.

```
NSString * s1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", c];
```